# How to prevent file from being downloaded and only open on chrome when SharePoint link is accessed?

Tags: sharepoint-online

we're currently transitioning a function to SharePoint. Files they upload are in TIFF format and when they copy the link to save in our systems, once this is accessed they are prompted to download the file. We do not want it to automatically download and we only want it to open in the browser when the link is accessed.

When the file is directly accessed from the SharePoint folder, we are able to view the file within the browser.

Is there any way I can stop the file from downloading automatically and just have it opened in the web browser? I've tried changing chrome settings but it still downloads on my laptop.

Comment: Can you please share a sample link. the fix will be in the link not in your browsers

Answer (score 0):

What is the meaning of “copy the link to save in our systems”? Where did you copy the link in the local system?

Per my test, I copy the link to the office 365 related software then I can directly open the picture.